# OAuth with twitter "React-Native/Meteor"

Tags: meteor, react-native, meteor-react

I'm working to implement an "**OAuth with twitter**" on a "**React-Native/Meteor project**" .. i searched but no results for React-Native/Meteor ... 
So can you help me by giving ***any informations*** about that ? 
i really need it

Comment: Please provide code around what you have already tried and what problems you are facing?

Comment: i am in first interaction with it so for now i just have a button for connecting with twitter (just a button without any event)..  and i search for the steps i can follow for implementing the OAuth with Twitter using React-Native connecting with Meteor app.